# Pulling SQL data for a row/range of values

Tags: sql, excel, vba

This code will work for me if I set the range for only D5. However, I want to run it continuously for the entire row of D values. Anytime I make that number more than a single cell it no longer works. Any advice?

```
Dim orderNo As Variant

orderNo = Sheet1.Range("D5:D7").Value
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Select BOM").OLEDBConnection
 .CommandText = "EXEC dbo.XXX '" & orderNo & "'"
 ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Select BOM").Refresh
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but `orderNo` is currently a 2D array that you can't concatenate with `&`. Do you want a loop?

Comment: Yes I would want to loop it for the entire D column

Comment: `Dim cell As Range`, `For Each cell in Sheet1.Range("D5:D7")`, `orderNo = cell.Value`?

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is working for one cell value. Put the with part inside of loop as below.

```
Dim orderNo as Range
For each orderNo in Sheet1.Range("D5:D7")
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Select BOM").OLEDBConnection
         .CommandText = "EXEC dbo.XXX '" & orderNo & "'"
         ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Select BOM").Refresh
    End With
Next orderNo
```